# what is an htmlclean plugin used for

Tags: jquery, plugins

what is this html clean thing in the following lines of code

```
$('body').html($.htmlClean($(this).html(), { allowedTags : ['a', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'br', 'p'] }));
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple Google search gives me the following page:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/

> Takes dirty dirty (X)HTML and produces nice clean XHTML (This will remove and clean html pasted from another source e.g. MS Word.)
>   It will;
>
> ```
> fix self closing tags
> lower-case tags
> remove non-standard attributes
> remove in-line style attributes
> remove in-line event attributes
> optionally remove other attributes
> tidy unnecessary white space and new lines
> remove conditional commenting
> remove proprietary word formatting tags
> replace tags e.g. i=>em
> optionally leave css classes in place
> format and indent html
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's the [JQuery HtmlClean plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/) being used. Which "Takes dirty dirty (X)HTML and produces nice clean XHTML "